# Clearing the keyboard buffer in Ada

Tags: keyboard, buffer, ada

I wrote a function to clear the keyboard buffer, since I think I am having leftover input after a get, but it's just taking input forever.

here is the get(String(1..10)

```
--getString10--
procedure getString10(s : in out string10) is
   Last: Integer;
begin
   s := (others => ' ');
   Get_Line(S, Last);
end getString10;
```

and here is the flush I made, pretty much copied from a wiki on clearing keyboard buffers

```
--flush--
procedure flush is
   char : character;
   more : boolean;
begin
   loop
      get_immediate(char, more);
      exit when not more;
   end loop;
end flush;
```

Whenever the flush is called, whatever I type is outputted on the screen until I exit the program.

Also, my getString10 function doesn't always wait on user input. For example, if I have

```
put("Enter a name: ");
getString10(name);
put("Enter a number: ");
getString10(number);
```

The output will be

```
Enter a name: Enter a number: exampleinput
```

I am using Ada 2005 on Gnat Programming Studio.

Updated with the entire main:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, BinarySearchTree;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure lab4 is

   subtype String10 is String(1..10);

   -- function "<"--
   function "<"(TheKey: in String10; ARecord: in String10) return Boolean is
   begin
      for i in integer range 1..10 loop
         if TheKey(i) <= ARecord(i) then
            return true;
         else
            return false;
         end if;
              end loop;

      return false;

   end "<";

   -- function ">"--
   function ">"(TheKey: in String10; ARecord: in String10) return Boolean is
   begin
      for i in integer range 1..10 loop
         if TheKey(i) >= ARecord(i) then
            return true;
         else
            return false;
         end if;
      end loop;

      return false;
   end ">";

   -- function "="--
   function "="(TheKey: in String10; ARecord: in String10) return Boolean is
   begin
      for i in integer range 1..10 loop
         if TheKey(i) /= ARecord(i) then
            return false;
             end if;
      end loop;

      return true;
   end "=";

   --getString10--
   procedure getString10(s : in out string10) is
      Last: Integer;
   begin
          s := (others => ' ');
      Get_Line(S, Last);
   end getString10;

   --flush--
   procedure flush is
      char : character;
      more : boolean;
   begin
      loop
         get_immediate(char, more);
         exit when not more;
      end loop;
   end flush;      

   package BST is new BinarySearchTree(String10, String10, "<", ">", "=");

   Root, found : BST.BinarySearchTreePoint;
   choice : integer;
   nameTemp, phoneTemp : String10;
begin
   BST.setRoot(Root);

   loop
      new_line;
      put_line("Options:");
      put_line("1 - Insert a record");
      put_line("2 - Find a person iteratively and print their phone number");
      put_line("3 - Find a person recursively and print their phone number");
      put_line("4 - Traverse the tree from a person to a person");
      put_line("0 - Quit program");
      put("Choose an option: ");
      get(choice); put(choice, 0); new_line;

      case choice is
         --case 1
         when 1 =>
            put("Enter the name: ");
            get(nameTemp); put(nameTemp); new_line;

            put("Enter the phone number : ");
            get(phoneTemp); put(phoneTemp); new_line;

            BST.InsertBinarySearchTree(root, nameTemp, phoneTemp);
         --case 2
         when 2 =>
            put("Enter the name of the person to find: ");
            get(nameTemp); put(nameTemp);
            BST.FindCustomerIterative(root, nameTemp, found);

            if BST.isNull(found) then
               new_line;
               put("Customer not found!");
            else
               new_line;
               put("The phone number is: ");
               put(BST.CustomerPhone(found));
            end if;
         --case 3
         when 3 =>
            put("Enter the name of the person to find: ");
            get(nameTemp); put(nameTemp);
            BST.FindCustomerRecursive(root, nameTemp, found);

            if BST.isNull(found) then
               new_line;
               put_line("Customer not found!");
            else
               new_line;
               put("The phone number is: ");
               put(BST.CustomerPhone(found));
            end if;
            new_line;

         --case 4
         when 4 =>
            put("Enter of the name of the person to start traversal at: ");
            get(nameTemp); put(nameTemp);
            BST.FindCustomerRecursive(root, nameTemp, found);

            put("Enter then name of the person to stop traversal at: ");
            get(phoneTemp); put(phoneTemp); --using phoneTemp for a name here

            BST.FindCustomerRecursive(Root, nameTemp, found);
            while BST.isNull(found) /= true loop
               put_line("Name = " & BST.CustomerName(found));
               BST.setNode(found, BST.InOrderSuccessor(found));
            end loop;

         --case 0
         when 0 =>
            exit;
         --others
         when others =>
            put_line("Invalid choice!"); new_line;
      end case;

   end loop;

end lab4;
```

I switched out all of the getString10()s with get()s because I am trying to debug the threaded binary search tree. I am using an input file, so it's fine for now, I just can figure out why the other methods wouldn't work.
All of the get calls on nameTemp and phoneTemp should be getString10() calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the get_line() function, which automatically clears the keyboard buffer.

```
with ADA.TEXT_IO;                use ADA.TEXT_IO;
with ADA.TEXT_IO.UNBOUNDED_IO;   use ADA.TEXT_IO.UNBOUNDED_IO;
with ADA.STRINGS.UNBOUNDED;      use ADA.STRINGS.UNBOUNDED;

procedure MAIN is

   type STRING_10 is new STRING(1..10);

   procedure GET_STRING_10(S : in out STRING_10) is
      BUF   :  UNBOUNDED_STRING;
   begin
      BUF := GET_LINE;

      for I in STRING_10'range loop
         if I <= LENGTH(BUF) then
            S(I) := ELEMENT(BUF, I);
         else
            S(I) := ' ';
         end if;
      end loop;
   end GET_STRING_10;

   S : STRING_10;

begin

   GET_STRING_10(S);
   PUT_LINE(STRING(S));

end MAIN;
```

EDIT after reading the whole main:
You should insert a `SKIP_LINE;` after `GET(CHOICE);`. Then you can replace every `GET` by a `GETSTRING10` in your different cases.

In general, a get must always be followed by a skip_line. There's no need to do this with a get_line, thus you don't have to modify you getstring10 procedure.

Comment: My getString10 uses the get_line() function, after I called it, it skipped the next getString10, which is why I thought there was a return char still in the buffer. Are you sure get_line clears the buffer?

Comment: @user1279914 I'm never sure of anything :) I do think that `GET_LINE` clears the buffer. However, I notice that many versions of `GET_LINE` exist [here](http://tinyurl.com/crtn2ez) and [here](http://tinyurl.com/d3dxuek). They might have a slightly different behavior that cause you big trouble. In the code above, I use a _function_ which takes _no args_ and which comes from the _unbounded io_ package. This one seems to be clearing the buffer. If you really need to use a _procedure_, could you please post more code (especially the imports) so that I can figure out which one you use exactly ?

Comment: @user1279914 What happens if you simply replace your flush function with a call to `SKIP_LINE` ?

Comment: Here is the weird thing. In Case 1 where I get the name and phone number, if I just switch out the get for getString10, the getString10(nameTemp) is skipped entirely, but the getString10(phoneTemp) works normally. That is why I thought there was an extra return skipping the first one. If I try skip_line after getting the name, I think the name becomes a new_line and it will skip the input from the user.