# Ada Input and Output issue

Tags: input, output, ada, gnat

After typing input from Integer it will automatically **skip** of getting the inputs from String. I don't know why?

Simple Ada code of getting inputs of String and Integer:

```
with ada.Text_IO; use ada.Text_IO;
with ada.Integer_Text_IO; use ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure Main is

   inputText: String (1..10);
   inputNmbr : Integer;
   StringNatural: Integer;  

begin

   Put_Line("Enter Integer");
   Get(inputNmbr,1);
   Put_Line("Enter String");
   Get_Line(inputText,StringNatural);
   Put_Line("===================");
   Put("Input for Integer: ");
   Put(inputNmbr,1);
   Put_Line("");
   Put_Line("Input for String: ");
   Put_Line(inputText(1..StringNatural));

end Main;
```

Output:

```
Enter Integer
2
Enter String
===================
Input for Integer: 2
Input for String: 

[2015-07-11 23:01:00] process terminated successfully, elapsed time: 00.86s
```

Answer (score 6):

`Get` won't clear the keyboard buffer, so you're having a carriage return sent to `Get_Line` as input. You can put a `Skip_Line` after `Get` to fix this:

```
Put_Line("Enter Integer");
Get(inputNmbr,1);
Skip_Line; -- add this
Put_Line("Enter String");
```

[`Skip_Line` documentation](http://www.cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs323/Ada/ada.html):

> Skip_Line is an input procedure and will cause the input to skip to the next line. This is useful to remove the carriage return from the input buffer. **Skip_Line should be performed after any call to a Get procedure.** It can also be used to make a program pause and wait for a carriage return to be entered.

See also: [Clearing the keyboard buffer in Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758078/clearing-the-keyboard-buffer-in-ada)

Comment: This is great! much appreciated for the help.

Comment: Notice that the advice on when to call `Skip_Line` isn't completely appropriate, as you may have cases, where you want to read multiple objects from the same line.

Comment: @ipavl can you please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410589/ada-getting-string-from-text-file-and-store-in-array